# Jquery div larger then smaller again with click on div

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I'm new to Jquery and could need some help.

https://jsfiddle.net/Ldvhx1ze/

After the div animates to 400px, i want it to go back down to 200px. What am i doing wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    if ($("#boks1").width() == 200) {

        $("#boks1").click(function () {
            $("#boks1").animate({
                width: "400px"
            });
        });


    } else {

        $("#boks1").click(function () {
            $("#boks1").animate({
                width: "100px"
            });
        });

    }

});
```

```css
html {
    width: 100%;
}
#test {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    margin: auto;
    animation: new-post 1s ease infinite;
}
#wrapper {
    height: 500px;
}
.container {
    background-color: black!important;
    margin-bottom: 40px!important;
}
#boks1 {
    height: 400px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}
#boks2 {
    height: 400px;
    width: auto;
}
#boks3 {
    height: 400px;
    width: auto;
}
#boks4 {
    height: 400px;
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div id="boks1"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div id="boks2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div id="boks3"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div id="boks4"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, what are your browser requirements? Do you need to do this with JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if statement is called on document ready, meaning the click event for `boks1` is always going to be the one to animate the width to 400px. Instead, detect the click, then check what the width is. Like this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#boks1").click(function(){
        if ($("#boks1").width() == 200){
            $("#boks1").animate({width: "400px"});
        } else {
            $("#boks1").animate({width: "200px"});
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You if-else logic is wrong

This will fix it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#boks1").click(function(){
         if ($("#boks1").width() == 200){
             $("#boks1").animate({width: "400px"});
         } else {
             $("#boks1").animate({width: "200px"});
         }
    });

});
```